# BackgroundColor + image of UIImageView to UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I have a `UIImageView` with some lines (drawed by hand) and a background color. When i put the image of the `UIImageView` into a `UIImage` and save it to the photo library the background is white again. Is there any way to put the image property and the `backGroundColor` property of a `UIImageView` into one `UIImage` ?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to render the contents of an arbitrary UIView to an UIImage.

See http://www.icab.de/blog/2010/10/01/scaling-images-and-creating-thumbnails-from-uiviews/ for an implementation.

At the bottom of that page is a category for UIImage which, when imported, simply lets you create the `UIImage` from the `UIView` with `UIImage *img = [UIImage imageFromView:someView];`

Comment: it doesn't work i used UIImage *imageToSave = [UIImage imageFromView:drawImage]; and i get an error 'UIImage' may not respond to -imageFromView.

Comment: OfCourse you will get an eror, if you haven't checked provided link!

You need to include necessary UIImage Category!

add MyImage.h, MyImage.m file to your project, 

import "MyImage.h"  in class you will use it, and :
    
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageFromView:someView];

will work :)